# How to add additional xmlns namespace attributes to XML in IE via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer

I'm a little bit stuck trying to attach multiple namespaces to an XML element via javascript across browsers; I've tried about a dozen different ways to no avail.

I usually use plain old javascript but for the sake of keeping this example short, this is how what I'm doing would be done via jQuery:

```
var soapEnvelope = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></soapenv:Envelope>';
var jXML = jQuery.parseXML(soapEnvelope);
$(jXML.documentElement).attr("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

In both Chrome and FF, this works as expected giving a result like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

But in IE9, I get a result like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:NS1="" NS1:xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```

And I cannot find a way to add this namespace attribute without IE9 adding this NS1 prefix to my namespaces. Also if I try passing this result back into $.parseXML(result) I get a malformed XML exception.

Am I misunderstanding something to do with the way namespaces are declared in IE or can anyone suggest a way I can get a consistent result across browsers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else runs into a similar problem to this, I ended up finding out that it can be fixed by initialising the IE XML DOM object differently to the way jQuery does it. I used something similar to the following and now the xml namespaces seem to be working fine across all major browsers and the jQuery attr method will now work again also.

```
var getIEXMLDOM = function() {
  var progIDs = [ 'Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0', 'Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0' ];
  for (var i = 0; i < progIDs.length; i++) {
    try {
        var xmlDOM = new ActiveXObject(progIDs[i]);
        return xmlDOM;
    } catch (ex) { }
  }
  return null;
}

var xmlDOM;
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
   xmlDOM = getIEXMLDOM();
   xmlDOM.loadXML(soapEnvelope);
} else {
   xmlDOM = jQuery.parseXML(soapEnvelope);
}

$(xmlDOM.documentElement).attr("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

Comment: +1. Anyway, you should modify your browser test. Currently you prefer the proprietary approach, but IE 9+ supports `window.DOMParser`, which is what jQuery defaults to internally. Don't do `if ( $.browser.msie )`, do `if ( !window.DOMParser )`. Also, here is a nice wrap-up about creating namespace declarations in MSXML: http://msmvps.com/blogs/martin_honnen/archive/2009/04/15/creating-xml-with-namespaces-with-javascript-and-msxml.aspx

Comment: Without jQuery: var objXmlDomParser = new DOMParser(); xmlDOM = objXmlDomParser.parseFromString(soapEnvelope, "text/xml"); xmlDOM.documentElement.setAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

Comment: And old IE: xmlDOM.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", 'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"');

Comment: @Tomalak Even with IE11, using jQuery default parser produced the issue mentioned by 2potatocakes. The best way I found without using custom browser code was to set all my namespaces before calling parseXML.